# How to shuffle the values in a hash?

Tags: perl, shuffle

I have a hash of string IDs. What is the best way to shuffle the IDs?

As an example, my hash assigns the following IDs:

```
this => 0
is => 1
a => 2 
test => 3
```

Now I'd like to randomly shuffle that. An example outcome would be:

```
this => 1
is => 0
a => 3
test => 2
```

Comment: You could always create a hash of different hashes and then randomly select from one of those ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `shuffle` method in [`List::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/Scalar-List-Utils-1.23/lib/List/Util.pm) to help out:

```
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

...

my @values = shuffle(values %hash);
map { $hash{$_} = shift(@values) } (keys %hash);
```

Comment: `map` in void context is an abomination.

Comment: Is that just a style issue or do you have a technical objection to it? (just curious)

Comment: Back when `map` returned the list (even in void context) it was a real issue.  These days it is just a style issue.  Some, like me, find it an abomination to rely on a side effect of a function do to work.  Especially when we have a construct that is just as short that doesn't use a side effect: `$hash{$_} = shift @values for keys %hash;`

Answer (score 4):

A hash slice would be the clearest way to me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw/shuffle/;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h = (
    this => 0,
    is   => 1,
    a    => 2,
    test => 3,
);

@h{keys %h} = shuffle values %h;

print Dumper \%h;
```

This has a drawback in that huge hashes would take up a lot of memory as you pull all of their keys and values out.  A more efficient (from a memory standpoint) solution would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw/shuffle/;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h = (
    this => 0,
    is   => 1,
    a    => 2,
    test => 3,
);

{ #bareblock to cause @keys to be garbage collected
    my @keys = shuffle keys %h;

    while (my $k1 = each %h) {
        my $k2 = shift @keys;
        @h{$k1, $k2} = @h{$k2, $k1};
    }
}

print Dumper \%h;
```

This code has the benefit of only having to duplicate the keys (rather than the keys and values).

The following code doesn't randomize the values (except on [Perl 5.8.1](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.1/pod/perldelta.pod#Hash_Randomisation) where the order of keys is guaranteed to be random), but it does mix up the order.  It does have the benefit of working in place without too much extra memory usage:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw/shuffle/;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h = (
    this => 0,
    is   => 1,
    a    => 2,
    test => 3,
);

my $k1  = each %h;
while (defined(my $k2 = each %h)) {
    @h{$k1, $k2} = @h{$k2, $k1};
    last unless defined($k1 = each %h);
}

print Dumper \%h;
```