# Randomise/Shuffle hash keys in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, random

I run through a hash various times, without changing the contents of the hash. I want the hash to iterate in a random order each time (I know that a hash's internal order is random, but I need that random order to change)

The code I want this for is below:

```
 for (my $i=1; $i<=$PopulationsizeA;$i++){ 
    my $P1 = rand;
    my $total=0; 
    my $Parent1='Parent1';
    my $P1A;
while ((my $Genotype1, my $Fitness1)=each (%Normalisedfithash)){
        $P1A=$P1-$total;

        if ($Parent1 eq 'Parent1'){ 
            if ($P1A<=$Fitness1){

                $Parent1=$Genotype1;
                $P1Tallyhash{$Genotype1}+=1; 

            }
            else{
                $total+=$Fitness1;
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

I need the order of %Normalisedfithash to randomly change for each iteration of the for loop. I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684209/how-to-shuffle-the-values-in-a-hash) however I don't want the values to randomly change keys but instead want the keys to keep their associated value but randomly change order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to shuffle the list of keys that you get back from the hash. `shuffle` from [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Util) is a good implementation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'shuffle';

...

foreach my $Genotype1( shuffle keys %Normalisedfithash ) { 
    my $Fitness1 = $Normalisedfithash{$Genotype1};
}
```

`shuffle` will shuffle the list in a different order each time.

Edit: I should say it will shuffle the list in a *random* order each time. The order might be the same as a previous time by coincidence. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

...
foreach my $Genotype1 (shuffle( keys %Normalisedfithash )) {
    my $Fitness1 = $Normalisedfithash{$Genotype1};
    ...
}
```